# MAMP работает очень медленно

Tags: mamp

У меня стоит MAMP и страницы почему-то загружаются очень медленно для поддомена типа `domainname.lc`.

Если загрузить сайт на сервер, то он начинает работать быстрее. В чем может быть проблема?

Я смотрел [вопрос на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452614/mamp-reloading-pages-is-very-slow), но он похоже устарел потому что сейчас MAMP сам добавляет эти записи.

У меня macOS HighSierra.

Comment: а скрипты стучатся куда-то? база данных может тупит? сам localhost работает в mamp как и должен, а вот связка с mysql даже локальной бывает дает тупки

Comment: Тупит даже если я ставлю MAMP, ставлю чистый движок (например вордпресс) и пытаюсь его открывать.